# static variable ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, variables, static

in asp.net web application if I want to store variable in a static object is that right?
I don't want that this object will share its value with another request.

```
public static object Objects
{
    get
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Items["Objects"] != null)
            return (object)HttpContext.Current.Items["Objects"];
        else
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Items["Objects"] = new object();
            return new object();
        }
    }

    set { HttpContext.Current.Items["Objects"] = value; }
}
```

THX

Comment: maybe you can store it in a Session Variable instead?

Comment: This is a very confusing question. `Objects` is not a variable, it is a property. HttpContext.Current.Items is not static, it is local to the request.

Comment: If you want to use a static variable without sharing it across all requests you could store a session variable in a static property. Use `HttpContext.Session` to access it.

Comment: Why are you *new*'ing up an object twice?

Comment: @MikeChristensen is right. The getter returns a different object than the one it caches, which is probably incorrect.

Comment: Although your question indicates there is a "static variable", no static variable is defined in your code. You only defined a static property. Properties are syntactic sugar for a get_ and set_ method. Methods by themselves do not have any state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static fields are shared across the whole AppDomain. This means that ALL requests in a ASP.NET web application will use the same value and you will have to make sure that variable is thread-safe. If this is not what you want, consider the following:

- Storing the value in the user session: `HttpContext.Current.Session`
- Storing the value in the request: `HttpContext.Current.Items`. This way the value is cached throughout the current request, but not shared across requests.
- Don't store the value at all.

In your case however, you are using a `static` property. This static property maps in your case to the `HttpContext.Current.Items`, which means that each request automatically gets its own variable and variables are not shared.

In other words, your code is thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want that this object will share its value with another
>   request.

You should not make it static then.

Comment: It should be fine, since the object being returned is stored in the `HttpContext`.

Comment: Adil, you didn't look at the code, making the property not static doesn't make any difference and your answer is therefore misleading.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a static variable without sharing it across all requests you could store a session variable in a static property. Use [`HttpContext.Session`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to access it.

```
public static object Objects  
{
    get
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Objects"] != null)
            return (object)HttpContext.Current.Session["Objects"];
        else
        {
            var obj = new object();
            HttpContext.Current.Session["Objects"] = obj;
            return obj;
        }
    }

    set { HttpContext.Current.Session["Objects"] = value; }
}
```

However, you should not return `object` but the correct type, that will increase readability, prevents exceptions and avoids always casting it where you use it.

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 main server Dictionary objects that store values between requests.
Application - shares values between all requests and users.
Cache - shares values between all requests and users but can be invalidated without restarting application.
Session - shares values between requests within the same session, all pages share the same session object, and is user specific.
ViewState - shares values between request but is page specific and user specific.

Answer (score -2):

if you want the benefit of static across a single request. That is, have a single request have access to the same value. Use a session variable instead.

```
Session['variable'] = value
```

this will store the value in the current session, this way you will have a different value per request.