# Is there any issue in making the properties as static in c# (in case of multiple access)

Tags: c#, asp.net, properties, static

I am developing a Web Application that allows multiple user access on it.

And in the code behind I am using a property in which i am saving some personal details of the user.

My question is, if I made those properties as static will be there any conflict in data saving in the property when multiple user doing the same thing.

Comment: _" a Web Application"_ with ASP.NET? If so, of course there will be conflicts since every user/request is a different thread that tries to access the static field. Don't do it if you don't have to.

Comment: Why would you want to make them static, when in fact they are not?

Comment: Check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14154892/scope-of-static-variable-in-multi-user-asp-net-web-application
Maybe this can help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [static variable ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303655/static-variable-asp-net)

Answer (score 7):

Do not do that. Static values are shared between user sessions so you would override those values for each different user.

Use `Session` or `Cookies` to store data for specific user.

Comment: There are other options (like `Cache`(app-scope) or `ViewState`(page+user-scope)): [Nine options for managing persistent user state in your ASP.NET application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

There will be issues if multiple people are using simultaneously and if he app is deployed.

Comment: So all OP has to do is not deploy. This is the best solution. +1

Comment: @weston: I don't see a _solution_. "There will be issues" is not even an answer imho.

Comment: @TimSchmelter It's genius. It's a sort of Schrodinger's software. It runs as long as you don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

static memebers are maintained only one copy which is common for all the users who see it, hence it's not good to use when you wnat to maintain it for multiple users.